# Rig a daz genesis character in blender

Tags: bones, rigify

I imported a Genesis character from Daz and want to rig it with Rigify.
But when I associate the rig to the mesh I have this error:
**Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones**
Then when I move the control rigs the mesh is not moving together.
I tried to merge by distance the mesh but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: try the "scale up 10x" trick. Scale up the armature and mesh 10x, parent to with auto weights, and reset the scale. Since you have locked all UI transformations and multiple mesh parts you have to unlock the scale first or use the armature to bypass the locks.

Comment: in a nutshell: 1) generate the rig from the meta rig. 2) parent all mesh objects to the armature (rig) with just *Parent To Object*. 3) select the armature and scale it up by factor 10 (keys S+1+0+Enter) 4) parent meshes again to the armature, this time *With Automatic Weights* => no error, the mesh will shrink. 5) select armature, reset scale (Alt+S) => the model is tiny now. 6) select mesh objects and clear parent (Alt+S) => the model has normal size again. 7) Parent mesh objects to the rig one more time, this time with *Empty Groups* to keep the weights untouched. Done.